# Why am I getting this Error with Apex/Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, querying

It is saying

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

But I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Each of these queries run on their own, but not together. What am I doing incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: try selecting the query that you want to run

Answer (score 3):

In Apex SQL Workshop, you can run only one query at a time. How?

- either by keeping only one query in the window and running it alone; then removing it and running another one (also alone)
- or, **select** one query (with a mouse - paint the whole query "blue") and run it (you can click the "Run" button, or press "CTRL + ENTER"). When you have one query selected, you can keep as many other queried there as you want. That's probably a better option. See the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood clearly then do you want get two different  report from the SQL quires. I am afraid , is this functionality (running two different quires) separately in the same region would be possible in oracle apex. That could be the reason the apex is throwing error.